# Windows 10 Insider Preview for commercial use

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider

Is it ok to use Windows 10 Insider Preview for commercial purposes ? By simply downloading the OS from

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced?wa=wsignin1.0

Or do you need to register as an organisation to the insider programme ?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be alright to use your machine for commercial reasons.  In order to use any version of Windows 10 requires a license.  Insider Preview builds expire so you will want to enable Windows Update and install new builds as they are released

Comment: @Ramhound: Because in a lot of cases free software is only allowed for personal/open source use or has other restrictions. For example Visual Studio Community version is free for open source but has some restrictions to use for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the preview, but be aware that you still need a valid license. Insider access just gives you the preview (beta) bits, not a full, valid license

Comment: thanks, but can you expand, not sure what you mean by valid license ? do I need to have a valid Windows license to use the free version ? What's the gain then :) ?

Comment: There is no "free" version. Not sure where you got that idea from? If you look at the Insider info: "The Windows Insider program is designed to give adventurous users the chance to try out the newest version of Windows before anyone else does" and further on: "To become an Insider, you'll need to have a copy of Windows 10 on your machine. Right now, you can still get Windows 10 for free, as long as you have a license for Windows 7, 8.." So yes, you are still required to have a full license for Windows